# Session is null when inherit from System.Web.UI.Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

I want to extend the System.Web.UI.Page-class with some extra stuff.
In the ctor I need the value of a session-variable.

The problem is that the Session-object is null...

```
public class ExtendedPage : System.Web.UI.Page {
   protected foo;   

   public ExtendedPage() {
      this.foo = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["foo"];   // NullReferenceException
   }
}
```

If I move the part with the session-object into the Load-Event everything works fine...

```
public class ExtendedPage : System.Web.UI.Page {
   protected foo;

   public ExtendedPage() {
      this.Load += new EventHandler(ExtendedPage_Load);
   }

   void ExtendedPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      this.foo = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["foo"];
   }
}
```

Why is the Session-object *null* in the first case??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Session` property is set later in the [Page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), after the `Page` object is constructed.

Comment: Do you mean that it's not set at construction but is set before page load?  (I think in pre-init.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to inherit the ExtendedPage class in an .aspx Page.

It will have Session when run in the HttpContext